# How to create a dropdown list to Select Day and Display Iframe tag linked to each day

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a HTML page that prompts the user to select a day from a drop down list. On selecting an option, I want the page to shows the schedule for that day. There are seven schedules that are defined in seven **iframe** tags.

I put together the code to select the Day but I am unable to figure out two things

1. How to place /code the relevant iframe tags with conditional statements?
2. How to show the relevant iframe without having to press the submit button?

To give some context, I am doing this for a school that allows students to select the day and know the schedule for the day.

```html
  <form>
  <label for="day">Choose a Day:</label>
  <select name="dayapp" id="dayapp">
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showlist()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#dayapp").change(function() {
// cheacks value of option on change
  if ($(this).val() == "Monday") {
  // if its some day do next:
$("iframe,span,br ").remove();
//removes previsuly added iframe (and for testing perpuspes i added span and new line)
    $( "#addiframe" ).append( " <span>Monday</span><br> <iframe id='Monday' src='https://www.w3schools.com' title='W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials'></iframe>" );
 //adds iframe (and for testing perpuspes span and new line) 
  }
  
  
  if ($(this).val() == "Tuesday") {
  $("iframe,span,br ").remove();
    $( "#addiframe" ).append( " <span>Tuesday</span><br><iframe id='Tuesday' src='https://www.w3schools.com' title='W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials'></iframe>" );
  }
  //etc
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="day">Choose a Day:</label>
  <select name="dayapp" id="dayapp">
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showlist()">
</form>

<div id="addiframe"></div>
```